# Проблемы с RenderBody

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Не давно начал работать в asp net mvc, после небольшой наработки страниц _Layout и Index в _Layout **RenderBody** начал создавать проблемы, то есть после него перестали выводиться данные, до него работает в нем работает а после него пусто, хотя раньше все данные были.

```
    <div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
    </footer>
</div>
<script src="~/Scripts/RotatingText.js"></script>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

может я что то удалил в Index.

Comment: А если посмотреть "исходный код страницы" в браузере? Тот, который пришел, а не построенное DOM дерево на F12. Возможно где-то не закрыли тег и браузер во время отображения выкинул эту информацию.

Comment: Да нет в браузере 0 ошибок да VS2017 уже бы сообщила о них

Answer (score 0):

Пришлось дописать за Microsoft, я думал что он будет растягивать автоматом сам

```
.body-content {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
```

}